# ajax charge principal page and after that the ajax container

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some trouble with ajax and principal page.
I have a page with one div, this is the container for the others page, when I do click in one link I want charge the principal page and after this action, charge some particular page in the container, I have this function

```
function goIndex(){
     window.location = '../index.php';   
}
```

In the index have a div with id "contenido"

```
<div id="contenido">
</div>
```

And I want do some like this:

```
function Enviar(_pagina, capa) {
    var ajax;
    ajax = ajaxFunction();
    ajax.open("POST", _pagina, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4)
        {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            } else if (ajax.status === 404) {
                Enviar('./404.php', 'contenido');
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.send(null);
}


function goIndex(){
 window.location = '../index.php';   
 Enviar('../php/portion.php', 'contenido');
}
```

but when I call the funcion goIndex from link this redirect to de index page but don't execute the second instruction to charge the portion of php in the container, It is as if he missed the second instruction.